# Flink redis connector: update getCommandDescription() after instantiation

Tags: redis, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using the FLink Redis Sink to write some counters to redis.
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/apis/streaming/connectors/redis.html

I would like to create a HASH  for each day however `getCommandDescription()` for the sink only gets called once when sink is instantiated. Is there a way to get that to update?

```
@Override
public RedisCommandDescription getCommandDescription() {
    long millis = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).withTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis();
    return new RedisCommandDescription(RedisCommand.HSET, "view_count_" + millis);
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to add the date in the HASH name. what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: figured out why. posted in ASF JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5478

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out, it is not currently supported. For the time being, you can maintain a timestamp key inside your hash.